# Change the way a collection is sorted through the client

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a collection that is shown on a page :

```
Template.body.helpers({
  chansonsFutures(){
    return Chansons.find({
      "playedStatus":false
    },{
      sort : { score:-1 }
    });
  },
});
```

And I would like the user to be able to change the way the collection is sorted. In the example it is sorted by `score`, but how would I go about sorted by something else?

I have a `select` in place :

```
  <select id="ordre">
    <option value="shuffle">Aléatoire</option>
    <option value="vote">Vote</option>
    <option value="lastAdded">Dernier Ajout</option>
  </select>
```

But if I put an `if` condition in `Template.body.helpers`, meteor tells my application has errors and is waiting for file changes. If I put the condition in `Template.body.events` and link it to the `change` of my `select`, it also gives me errors.

How should I proceed?

edit : to answer @Justinas, here is how I put the condition in code.

My first try was straight in the helper :

```
Template.body.helpers({

if(document.getElementById("ordre").value == "lastAdded"){
  chansonsFutures(){
    return Chansons.find({
      "playedStatus":false
    },{
      sort : { lastAdded:-1 }
    });
  },
};

else if (other value for the select) {
    other stuff happens
};
});
```

And the other way was like this :

```
Template.body.events({

  'change #ordre'(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    chansonsFutures(){

      return Chansons.find({
        "playedStatus":false
      },{
        sort : { document.getElementById("ordre").value:-1 }
      });
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you show how you put that condition in code?

Comment: @Justinas I added them to my post

Comment: Have you tried using reactive variables and ordering them in the publisher in the server?

Comment: @Orozcorp I still have autopublish turned on, but what you're saying is that when it is disabled I should sort already in the publisher? I'm still new to Meteor, so I guess a reactive variable is one that looks like `{{variable}}` ?

Comment: Yes, it is preferible to sort in the server.  And no please check https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html and https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables  and https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is what you need to add in your js fiile :

By defalult it will sot by 'score' and on changing select value it will change accordingly.

```
    Template.body.onCreated(function() {
      this.sortBy = new ReactiveVar('score');
    })
    Template.body.helpers({

      chansonsFutures : function(){
        var sortParam = Template.instance().sortBy.get();
        return Chansons.find({
          "playedStatus":false
        },{
          sort : { sortParam:-1 }
        });
      },
    });


 Template.body.events({
       'change #ordre':function (event,templateInstance) {
         var sortSelected = $('#ordre option:selelcted').val();
         templateInstance.sortBy.set(sortSelected)
       }
    })
```

Comment: `templateInstance.sortby.set(sortSelected)` should be `templateInstance.sortBy.set(sortSelected)`, but this worked ! Thanks a bunch

Comment: Changes Done. Thanks !

Comment: Hey ! Just one last thing. `sort : { sortParam:-1 }` should instead be `sort : { [sortParam]:-1 }`. You need the brackets, otherwise Meteor doesn't understand sortParam is a variable.